# Deploy multiple Angular 2 apps

Tags: angular, nginx, webpack

I am really stuck in the problem where we deploy several angular applications in the same server.
I have done

```
ng build --prod
```

in earch project, but my problem is how to put all projects together.
I take all of your proposals.
Thank you.

***EDIT***

After some research found how can deploy all angular project together using nginx.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /home/radouani/pf;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location /App1/dist {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }
```

But the problem is It can not load my css and js file any idea?

Comment: What are you deploying the website to? IIS, Apache, Herkou , etc.

Comment: The server is nginx Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to put together? Each project should be in dedicated folder?

Comment: @can you have a look to the edit please